# Export development certificate as p12

Tags: ios, certificate, export

I downloaded a personal development certificate from the Apple Developer center and imported it to my keychain. Now, I want to export it as a .p12 file and encrypt it with a password. When I right click the certificate in the Keychain tab Certificates, and press the Export button, the .p12 option is not highlighted/available. Instead of the other 3 options (.cer, .pem, .p7b), which are available.

I tried a couple of things yet, like adding the Apple ID, which was used to create the certificate, to System preferences->Users and Groups->My account, but that didn't solve it. The certificate was created on a different Macbook than I'm using now.

Is it possible to export it as a .p12 in any way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The missing `.p12` option means that you only have either the private key or the certificate on your machine. You need both of these to generate a `.p12` (and incidentally, you'll need both the private key and certificate to sign your apps).

So, find out which of these you're missing, add the missing piece to Keychain, and the `.p12` option will be available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The certificate is in the Keychain, so it might be the private key. Since the private key is on the machine where the certificate is created, it won't be possible to create a .P12 on my machine, right?

Comment: When you first generated your developer certificate, you first had to create a CSR (certificate signing request) with Keychain. This puts the private key in your Keychain. You then submit the CSR to the Apple Developer portal, which would give you the certificate back. So, short answer is, the machine you did that initial CSR step from would have the private key in its Keychain (if it hasn't been deleted).

Comment: @tom what if the certificate is downloaded from apple developer settings and not generated from the machine?

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question of how to get the original private key. The answer I have found is to import an old p12 file that used the private key; the key will be imported, even though the certificate has expired. There seems no way to import the key only; people talk about ssh-add but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 55):

One point of interest: the Keychain Assistant window has a "Category" list in the right pane below the title bar (used to be in the lower part of the left panel). **You can only export a p12 from the "(My) Certificates" view.**

In the "All Items" view, you can see the certificates and the keys alongside, so that they're distinct items with no possibility of multiple selection; in the Certificates view, there's a tree structure with keys as child items of certificates, so that selecting a certificate implicitly selects the corresponding private key too.

Comment: lol, This answer was the right one I've been searching for a long time.

Comment: Saved me at least 10 minutes, probably a lot more.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, this was immensely helpful.

Comment: You can also select both the private key and the certificate in the All Items view before doing the export and that will allow p12... but this Certificates Category view is easier

Comment: Honestly sometimes I wish Apple would just stop trying to make software and stick to making wearable fashion accessories.

Answer (score 2):

You can check in your keychain whether the private key is associated with the development certificate.
You can export the private key and certificate as .p12 only if it is there.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue - I was able to sign macOS applications locally with my "Developer ID certificate", but wasn't able to export that certificate as a .p12 file (required by Azure Pipelines). What I found after maybe an hour of trying everything is that you need to store the Developer ID certificate in the "login" keychain (only there you can see also your private key and the "Export as .p12" option), not in the "System" keychain as I used to have for many years...

So although the Developer ID certificate stored in the System keychain works fine with Xcode, it doesn't allow you to export it as a .p12 file until you reimport it to the "login" keychain...

[image: System keychain]
[image: Login keychain]

Comment: No, that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you created the certificate by generating the CSR file from the same mac computer. There is a chance that your private key and certificate (after importing the .cer file into your Keychain Access app) is in different keychains. ***Make sure they both are in same keychain***.

For example, I had my private key inside "login" keychain and the certificate inside "System" keychain. ***What I did is dragged the .cer file into the "login" keychain*** it worked like magic. Now I could see the dropdown along with the certificate which shows the relevant private key.

Answer (score -4):

[image: Just select Certificate from the left panel to export it as .p12]
Just select Certificate from the left panel to export it as .p12